# Splitting a row containing JSONB string array into two different rows (PostgreSQL)

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb

Given a row that looks like this (PostgreSQL 10 and 11):

```
CREATE TABLE examples (
    "id" varchar NOT NULL,
    "type" varchar NOT NULL,
    "relation_id" varchar NOT NULL,
    "things" jsonb,
    PRIMARY KEY ("id")
);

INSERT INTO examples(id, type, relation_id, things) values
('7287b283-f2d8-4940-94ae-c8253599d479', 'letter-number', 'relation-id-1', '["A", "B", "1", "2", "C"]');
INSERT INTO examples(id, type, relation_id, things) values
('7287b283-f2d8-4940-94ae-c8253599d480', 'letter-number', 'relation-id-2', '["A", "2", "C"]');
INSERT INTO examples(id, type, relation_id, things) values
('7287b283-f2d8-4940-94ae-c8253599d481', 'letter-number', 'relation-id-3', '[]');
```

How would you go ahead and split those rows into:

`'7287b283-f2d8-4940-94ae-c8253599d480', 'relation-id-1', 'number', '["2"]'`

`'7287b283-f2d8-4940-94ae-c8253599d482', 'relation-id-1', 'letter', '["A", "C"]'`.

Essentially split the "type" field and conditionally divide the jsonb array.

Assumptions:

1. Values in the JSONB are always there (they can be an empty array) but they are always structured like that.
2. There are other `types` in the same table.
3. Keeping the relation_id is crucial.
4. The values that go inside the JSONB array are know, there is only a couple of them (lets say five or six) so **we can hardcode them in the query**.
5. Changes have to be persisted. The original row can be removed/updated.

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4VV1tZD3pBYMiCmtTFtQnj/5 <- DB-fiddle.

I tried messing around with `json_array_elements` and `INSERT ... SELECT` with a subquery but that got me nowhere for now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Click: demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=880e9204a5b785ce3048edd42260b895)

```
SELECT
    id,
    relation_id,
    CASE WHEN elems ~ '[0-9]' THEN 'number' ELSE 'letter' END AS type,  -- 2
    jsonb_agg(elems)                                   -- 3
FROM
    examples,
    jsonb_array_elements_text(things) elems            -- 1
GROUP BY 
    1,2,3                                              -- 3
```

1. Expand the array into one row per element
2. Check if element is digit using a regular expression. If so, create new type number, otherwise letter
3. Group by this new type and reaggregate the elements

---

With extensions:

- Update the table with the split rows (remove old, insert new)
- Empty arrays generate rows with both types

[Click: demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=3e3de223a51a114b7ea4392b7c3ed871)

```
WITH del AS (
    DELETE FROM examples
    RETURNING id, relation_id, type, things
)
INSERT INTO examples
SELECT
    id || '_' || type,
    relation_id, 
    type, 
    COALESCE(jsonb_agg(elems) FILTER (WHERE elems IS NOT NULL), '[]')
FROM (
    SELECT
        id,
        relation_id,
        CASE WHEN elems ~ '[0-9]' THEN 'number' ELSE 'letter' END AS type,
        elems
    FROM
        del,
        jsonb_array_elements_text(things) elems

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
        id,
        relation_id,
        t,
        null
    FROM
        examples,
        unnest(array['number', 'letter']) as t
    WHERE things = '[]'
) s
GROUP BY 1,2,3;
```

Comment: That looks like a great answer (at least a great insight into how to go about it) but it doesn't update/insert new rows. I'll update the question to make it more clear.

Comment: Here is a possible update using a DELETE and INSERT in the same query with the help of a CTE clause: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=27436a80d16e971c08e157cfd57b1cfa The only difference: The unique id is calculated simply by adding the new type instead of finding the next logical hex value which does not currently exist. This logic maybe has to be inserted by your own. The question was about splitting the JSON array, right?

Comment: Yes, the question is mainly about splitting that array. The IDs and the rest I think I can handle on my own, I wanted to simplify the example to ask as specific question as possible.

Comment: Yes! This works perfectly well. My only gripe with this is that rows that have `[]` will get lost. Can you at least point me in the correct direction how to preserve rows with empty JSON arrays and still get two rows (both with `[]`)? Would it be an additional `when` in a `case` statement?

Comment: This can be solved using a UNION: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=b1a56d536022303c6e5ddf79d628569b Here I created a new type for empty arrays, but you can change this of course

Comment: Yes, this looks closely to what I need. To have perfect answer we'd need two rows `letter` with `[]` and `number` with `[]`. No third type, just split as usual but both get empty array. I'll accept the answer at that point, great work. I really need to up my json game. :D

Comment: Haha, you are challenging me ;) https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=3e3de223a51a114b7ea4392b7c3ed871 Is this something which you can accept ;)

Comment: Looks perfect! Ideally what the question asked. I'll mark you answer as correct, you can update the answer as you see fit (the last fiddle answers the question fully). :)